# Как игнорировать ненужные символы в C++ (по типу C)

Tags: c++, c, вывод, ввод, форматирование

В **языке С** я могу написать:

```
int a, b;
scanf("%d:%d", &a, &b);
printf("%d %d", a, b);
```

При вводе в консоль, например, **"10:20"**, я получу на выводе **"10 20"**.
Язык С будет игнорировать двоеточие.

**Вопрос: как сделать так в С++, чтобы *cin* принимал два значения, но игнорировал определенные символы?**

Comment: скопировать/вставить?

Comment: функция scanf библиотечная, а не встроенная в язык, поэтому она есть и в `C` и в `C++`

Answer (score 0):

Нет встроенной возможности в cin не читать некоторые символы. Однако, вы можете пойти на хитрость:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    char symbol;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::cin >> symbol;
        std::cout << symbol << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Если ввести программе любые пять букв, то в каждом повторении цикла `symbol` будет принимать по букве. Вы можете сделать проверку на отброс символов, например двоеточия:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
int main(){
    char symbol;
    std::string str;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::cin >> symbol;
        if (symbol != ':'){ //проверка на двоеточие
            str += symbol;
        } else {
            str += ' ';
        }
    }
    std::cout << str << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

При вводе `10:20` в строке `str` будет `10 20`. Если вы хотите записать и 10, и 20 в числовые переменные, по приплюсовывайте символы к друм строкам, `:` будет разделителем, а строки нужно будет превратить в переменные:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
int main(){
    char symbol;
    bool flag = false; //false - запись в первую строку, true - во вторую
    std::string int1;
    std::string int2;
    int a;
    int b;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::cin >> symbol;
        if (symbol != ':' and flag == false){
            int1 += symbol;
        } else if (symbol != ':' and flag == true) {
            int2 += symbol;
        } else {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    a = std::stoi(int1);
    b = std::stoi(int2);
    std::cout << a << "\n" << b << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

При вводе 10:20 будет два int: 10 и 20

Comment: Неправда, есть. Есть  способ переопределить   символы разделители

Comment: Тогда я не знаю

Comment: см. `std::ctype`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете предварительно смотреть буквы в потоке с помощью `peek` и читать нужный тип : букву или число.

```cpp
int h ;
std :: cin >> h ;
char c = std :: cin . peek ( ) ;
if ( c == ':' ) {
  char cd ;
  std :: cin >> cd ;
}
int m ;
std :: cin >> m ;
std :: cout << "h = " << h << " : m = " << m << std :: endl ;
```

получаем :

```
10:20
h = 10 : m = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью `std::ctype` можно создать необычную локаль где `:` считается пробелом. Код на основе cppreference-примера для `ctype`:

```
#include <locale>
#include <vector>

struct colon_locale: std::ctype<char> 
{
    colon_locale(): std::ctype<char>{get_table(), false} {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table() {
        static std::vector<mask> masks {classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size};
        masks[':'] |=  space; // пробел
        masks[' '] &= ~space; // не пробел?
        return masks.data();
    }
}; 

#include <iostream>
    
int main() {
    std::vector<int> values;
    std::cin.imbue(std::locale{std::locale(), new colon_locale{}});

    do {
        int v;
        std::cin >> v;
        values.push_back(v);
    } while (std::cin);
    
    for(auto & v : values)
        std::cout << v << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Это поменяет поведение всего потока . Если нужен смешанный (сложный) ввод, лучше создать свой собственный интерпретатор